# VUE 2.0 - Unable to get props id through $router.push to details page

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vuejs2

I have a list of Tickets which works fine (companytickets), and when clicked.. it opens up a details page (companyticket) for that specific ticket, passing the id to the component.

problem is i can't find out how to access this prop parameter in the created event, since it's not accessable through "this".

**companytickets.vue :**

```
            viewTicket: function(ticket){
            this.$router.push('/companyticket/' + ticket.Id)
            // works : this redirects to http://localhost:8180/companyticket/3
        }
```

**companyticket.vue**

```
export default {
  name: 'CompanyTicket',
  props: {
    id: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
      }
  },
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('getCompanyTicket', this.id)
    // ERROR : this.id is undefined...
    console.log("Created here :")
  }
}
```

**route config**

```
{ path: '/companyticket/:id', component: CompanyTicket, props: true }
```

**Scenario**

- this.id is "undefined"
- when using this.$route.params.id i get the correct id parameter, but in some weird way it claims to use "companytickets/2" (which is the parent page). The Correct should be companyticket/2.

**Screenshot of Chrome Dev :**
[image]

Comment: try using mounted instead of created?

Comment: Tried... this.id is still undefined.. 

I will update the question with a screenshot now...

Comment: Updated question with mounted state, and you can see "this".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **object-style or payload** for passing params to actions.
Change:

```
this.$store.dispatch('getCompanyTicket', this.id)
```

To:

```
this.$store.dispatch("getCompanyTicket", {
    id: this.id 
})
```

Now your files looks like this:

**companyticket.vue**

```
created() {
    this.$store.dispatch("getCompanyTicket", {
        id: this.id 
    })       
  }
```

**store.js**

```
  actions: {
    getCompanyTicket({ commit }, { id })  {         
        console.log("ID is available now-->", id)
    }
  }
```

### Vuex

Since you're using Vuex state management pattern, that would be another approach to share data between component. 
It allow parent-child communication and same for child-parent (*sharing data with props allow only parent-child communication*). Inject store into to your root component:

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  // provide the store using the "store" option.
  // this will inject the store instance to all child components.
  store,
})
```

This is everything you need in your store object:

```
var store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        ticketID: Number
    },
    mutations: {
        UPDATE_TICKET_ID(state, ticketId) {
            state.ticketId = ticketId;
        }
    },
    actions: {
        getCompanyTicket({ commit, state }, { id })  {         
            commit("UPDATE_TICKET_ID", id)
        }
    }
}
```

Also if you want to update state:

> The only way to actually change state in a Vuex store is by committing
>   a mutation

Any property from state will be available in every component:

```
console.log(this.$store.state.ticketId)
```

Comment: Good thought.. but.. it doesn't seem like "this" got access to anything called "id" at all. this.id returns "undefined".

Comment: is there any other way i can access the id ? is "this" the wrong context ?

Comment: Because you're using Vuex, other way would be saving ID to the store.state. So that ID would be available in all Vue components and also in same store objects -mutations, actions.

Comment: But I'm sure that first approach where we passing id in object needs to work. "this" refer to prop id, and it's available in Vuex action. Did you try it?

Comment: Well.. i have a quite funny update on this : this.id is "undefined" on my windows laptop, but on my collegues "macbook"... this.id is 1.

Comment: any chance if i give you my code you could take a look at it and see if there's any reason for this ? (Alternative... another approach of id handling ?

Comment: I updated my answer with Vuex approach, to store data in state, and use that state in components. You can look that, and you can share code on jsFiddle  if nothing of this work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135986/discussion-between-t-dom93-and-terje-nygard).

Comment: well actually... i got it figured out this afternoon.. Appearantly.. my collegue which had a mac got it working like it should, and then i though that deleting the node_modules and running a new npm install might fix the issue.. and it did !!! :) But your help here.. was precious, and it solved most of the issues i had with this.. so thanx a bunch mate :) This answer is the right one, and will be accepted as correct answer.